# StoredProcedures and Functions transferred with different schema name while using Transfer SQL Server Objects task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-schema, database-migration

I'm trying to move SQL Server objects i.e.,tables,views,stored procedures,user defined functions from one database to another using Transfer SQL server objects Task in SSIS.

Tables,views are properly transferred into the destination database with the same schema name as in source database . However,some of the stored procedures and user defined functions are changed to one of the schemas in the destination database upon completing the transfer.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: So `custom.proc1` => `dbo.proc1` while `other.proc2` => `other.proc2`?

Comment: Hi,  It's  dbo.proc1 => dbo.proc1 while dbo.proc2 => otherschemaname_in_samedb.proc2 . Is there a way that I can copy as it is as in source ? Pls help.

Comment: Hi, Any update for solution on this please? Thanks.